# Passing value to Symbol.iterator

Tags: javascript, generator, ecmascript-6

If I define an iterator for an object and create an instance, I can iterator over those values, as expected:

```
class Hello {
  *[Symbol.iterator]() {
    yield 5;
   }
  *iterator (value) {
    yield value;
  }
}

var hello = new Hello();

for (let val of hello) {
  console.log(val); // 5
}

for (let val of hello.iterator('wow')) {
  console.log(val); // 'wow'
}
```

In the previous example, the `[Symbol.iterator]` is declared as a generator. I can declare another generator and pass arguments to it, but is there a way to pass arguments to the default iterator?

I've tried the following, but it throw an error:

```
for (let val of hello('wow')) {
  console.log(val); // 5
}

// Uncaught TypeError: hello is not a function
```

Am I missing something? Or is this just not possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you pass a value to be iterated in a `for…of` loop, it needs to implement the *iterable* interface - that is, its `Symbol.iterator` method will be implicitly called with no arguments and should return an iterator.

You also can pass iterators directly, as all iterators are "iterable", their `Symbol.iterator` method just returns themselves.

So while there is no way to make a `for…of` loop call the default iterator with special arguments, you always can call the method yourself and pass the iterator:

```
var hello = {
  *[Symbol.iterator](val) {
    yield val;
  }
};
for (let val of hello[Symbol.iterator]('works')) {
  console.log(val); // 'works'
}
```

Comment: That's really ugly, but it totally answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how it is ugly - it's just the same as your original `.iterator` method call. But I wonder anyway *why* you are doing this, maybe that's why it feels ugly?

Comment: I was making a graph like API where you could iterate over all nodes (including orphans) or pass a node to the iterator and just iterator over adjacent nodes. In my mind, it makes sense that would be the default behavior, but because of this syntax (and only because of this syntax!) I'll just make another iterator where you have to pass a node. That isn't a bad solution in any way.

Comment: Yeah, those really should be two different methods. Btw, the native `Map` API has a default `[Symbol.iterator]()` method that is also accessible as `.entries()`.